# how to add components in JPanel at run time

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, jtextfield

```
private void add_subActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
try{
jPanel3.add(new JLabel("Subject"));
jPanel3.add(new JTextField(20));
jPanel3.revalidate();
jPanel3.repaint();

}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e);
}
}
```

I have this code to add components in Panel at run time using button action
the code does not show any error but the components are not visible on the panel
please help

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Hard to tell without it.

Comment: I have button named add_sub when i click that buttonn there should be a jlabel and a jtextfield added in my jpanel at run time

Comment: You might want to read more on layout managers first: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you use any layout or you place coordinates manually, but I guess you have three errors with your code : 
 - Where is the place the new elements have to pop ?
 - Which size it must have ?
 - With this code, every action will pop your JLabel and JTextField.

I think you can have a fourth issue : you add it EVERYTIME you perform any action. So you will have a stack of your elements if you don't change coordinates.

Comment: i had used a flow layout

Comment: please if possible give me the code...i would  appreciate

Comment: I don't have any to provide, but this can help you : __See which case is interesting for you to listen. In your code, it might be "click" action. __Add references to your objects Jlabel and JTextField in your class (if you can). Then you just have to use the references to control what you're adding.